# How can I include a failure screenshot to the testNG report

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng

currently I am taking screenshots of my test failures this way:

```
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun=true)
public void catchExceptions(ITestResult result){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss");
    String methodName = result.getName();
    if(!result.isSuccess()){
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File((String) PathConverter.convert("failure_screenshots/"+methodName+"_"+formater.format(calendar.getTime())+".png")));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Can I include my own screenshots into the TestNG report link or pic? If yes how?

All I found on that online is the FEST framework. But since I am already taking the screenshots I dont want to use another framework.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can include the link to your screenshot in testng report.

You need to call `org.testng.Reporter.log` method to write the hyperlink to the [testng](/questions/tagged/testng) report either by annotating your test class or parent of all testclasses with @Listeners({yourListener.class}) or by adding the listener to your `testng.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="default">
  <listeners>
    <listener class-name="ScreenshotListener" />
  </listeners>
  <test name="Test">
    <packages>
      <package name="someTests.*"/>
    </packages>
  </test>
</suite>
```

You need to first create a Listener class and add it to testng. You can get details for that from testng.org. Search for listener.

Once you create that class, you should write a method in it which overrides the `ontestfailure` method. The code inside this method will be executed whenever testng identifies a failure.

You can call your screenshot grabbing method and use `Reporter.log` to put the hyperlink to that screenshot. Then you can find this link under the failed testcases details.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;

import org.testng.*;

public class ScreenshotListener extends TestListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss");
        String methodName = result.getName();
        if(!result.isSuccess()){
            File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)SomeStaticWebDriver.driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            try {
                String reportDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).getAbsolutePath() + "/target/surefire-reports";
                File destFile = new File((String) reportDirectory+"/failure_screenshots/"+methodName+"_"+formater.format(calendar.getTime())+".png");
                FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, destFile);
                Reporter.log("<a href='"+ destFile.getAbsolutePath() + "'> <img src='"+ destFile.getAbsolutePath() + "' height='100' width='100'/> </a>");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there away to place the link/pic in the results? Like under the failed method name or something like that?

Comment: Yes. You need to first create a Listener class and add it to testng. You can get details for that from testng.org. Search for listener. Once you create that class, you should write a method in it which overrides the ontestfailure method. The code inside this method will be executed whenever testng identifies a failure. You can call your screenshot grabbing method and use Reporter.log to put the hyperlink to that screenshot. Then you can find this link under the failed testcases details.

Comment: Thanks for the quick guide :-) I ll try that when I am back at work.

Comment: Excellent. Worked like a charm. Fascinating, how such a short description can be helpful;) A bit more details. Extend TestNG TestListenerAdapter, implement onTestFailure as in the question above plus add at the end Reporter.log("<a href='" + screenshotFile.getAbsolutePath() + "'>screenshot</a>");, annotate your test class or parent of all testclasses with @Listeners({yourListener.class}). And you're done.

Comment: @A.J My approach was just as you had suggested (I added my listener to testng.xml instead annotating my base test class with @Listener). But my testNG report does not attach the screenshots. Instead it treats <img> as text. My Reporter.log entry looks as:        Reporter.log("<img src=\"file://" + fullFileName + "\" alt=\"\" height='100' width='100' /><br/>");  Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually, the screenshot IS attached to index.html. But the img tag is still treated as text in emailable-report.html. I would prefer to have the screenshots in emailable-report.html so I can email the screenshots along with the test results. How can I achieve this? How is this report different?

Comment: @Harini I am assuming you are running this test from eclipse using testNG plugin. You need to go to properties of your project, then to testNG section and check the option-use project testng jar. Your issue will be resolved

Comment: @A.J Thanks for the quick reply. I actually run my tests using maven. Do I need to make any changes to my POM.xml?

Comment: @Harini Sorry i don't know how to make that change in Maven project.

Comment: @A.J My <img> tags are also displayed as text. I changed the setting in Eclipse that you mentioned but I see no changes in my emailable report. Any thoughts on that? Thanks!

Comment: @Cagy79 If you have selenium-standalone.jar and testng.jar in your library path, you need to change the ordering of jar files. I assume that selenium.jar has an older version of testNG which is causing this weird behavior.

Comment: I wanted to just use an `@AfterMethod`  to capture the screenshot and a link to the report. The key was calling `Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(result);` in that case before calling `Reporter.log`.

Answer (score 1):

Customizing a bit of ExtentReport can give extremely useful report having exception+screenshot captured exactly at time of test failure . Screenshot can be placed alongside exception which user can use to know what was website doing when error occurred.

Report Example
[image]
Test

```
      @Test (enabled=true)                           
        public void verifySearch() {
       extentlogger = extent.createTest("To verify verifySearch");
      //Your other code here.....
        soft.assertEquals("xxx", "xxxx");
        soft.assertAll();
      }
```

AfterMethod

```
     @AfterMethod
     public void getResult(ITestResult result) throws Exception{
      if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
     {
        extentlogger.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getThrowable() + 
        " - Test Case Failed", ExtentColor.RED));
    
        try {
        // get path of captured screenshot using custom failedTCTakeScreenshot method
        String screenshotPath = failedTCTakeScreenshot( result);
        extentlogger.fail("Test Case Failed Snapshot is below " + 
      extentlogger.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath));
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
     }
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the original question