# How to substitute path to get screenshot in emailable report or index.html

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

```
String filePath = screenShotName.toString()

String path = "img src="\"file://"" alt="\"\"/" 

Reporter.log(path)
```

I want to get a screenshot in emailable report or index.html

What should I put as `img`'s `src`, `file` and `alt`?

Comment: please clarify, a screenshot of what do you need? Provide some relevant code for context

Comment: This is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939337/how-can-i-include-a-failure-screenshot-to-the-testng-report

Answer (score 0):

Path to locate Screeshot:

You need to just create Screenshots folder in your project directory at root location,

```
File filetest = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toFile();
ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File(filetest + "\\Screenshots\\" +  " - " + ".png"));
```